# Using python manage.py migrate --check in kubernetes readinessProbe never succeeds

Tags: django, kubernetes, django-migrations

I have a django deployment on kubernetes cluster and in the `readinessProbe`, I am running `python`, `manage.py`, `migrate`, `--check`. I can see that the return value of this command is 0 but the pod never becomes ready.

Snippet of my deployment:

```
      containers:                                                                             
        - name: myapp                                                                      
          ...
          imagePullPolicy: Always                                                             
          readinessProbe:                                                                     
            exec:                                                                             
              command: ["python", "manage.py", "migrate", "--check"]                          
            initialDelaySeconds: 15                                                           
            periodSeconds: 5
```

When I describe the pod which is not yet ready:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  66s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ...  Normal   Pulled     66s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image ...
  Normal   Created    66s                kubelet            Created container ...
  Normal   Started    66s                kubelet            Started container ...
  Warning  Unhealthy  5s (x10 over 50s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed:
```

I can see that `migrate` `--check` returns 0 by execing into the container which is still in not ready state and running

```
python manage.py migrate
echo $?
0
```

Is there something wrong in my exec command passed as `readinessProbe`?

The version of kubernetes server that I am using is 1.21.7.
The base image for my deployment is python:3.7-slim.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the readiness probe? Does the pod start if you remove it?

Comment: Yes, it does start if I remove the readiness probe.

Comment: Did you [try `timeoutSeconds`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes)? Which Kubernetes version are you using? Which base image are you using for your application? Could you also share some code for endpoint used for probe?

Comment: @MikolajS. I have updated the question with the version of k8s that I am using. For endpoint probe, I have already listed my command and it is inbuilt function / feature of python/django which returns 0 in case of there are no migrations to run.

Comment: @MikolajS. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The problem was timeoutSeconds. I didn't realise that its default value is 1. It obviously takes more time than that. After increasing this value, it is now able to pass the readinessProbe. If you could add your comment as answer, I will accept the answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the issue is to increase [`timeoutSeconds` parameter, which is by default set to 1 second](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes):

> - `timeoutSeconds`: Number of seconds after which the probe times out. Defaults to 1 second. Minimum value is 1.

After increasing the `timeoutSeconds` parameter, the application is able to pass the readiness probe.

Example snippet of the deployment with `timeoutSeconds` parameter set to 5:

```yaml
      containers:                                                                             
        - name: myapp                                                                      
          ...
          imagePullPolicy: Always                                                             
          readinessProbe:                                                                     
            exec:                                                                             
              command: ["python", "manage.py", "migrate", "--check"]                          
            initialDelaySeconds: 15                                                           
            periodSeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 5
```